Glass material in Qt3D C++ program?
I am writing a simulation program in C++ that renders a 3D scene in a QML Scene3D object from C++. It works well, but I would like to add almost transparent cone meshes to the scene.
I tried using Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial with low alpha values, but the result is not transparent enough. In fact using an alpha value of zero produces solid white objects.
    Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh *m_cone = new Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh(e);
    
    Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial *conemat = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial(e);
    QColor coneColor = QColor::fromRgbF(0,0.5,0,0);
    conemat->setDiffuse(coneColor);
    conemat->setAlphaBlendingEnabled(true);
 
    m_cone->setBottomRadius(1798444);
    m_cone->setTopRadius(0);
    m_cone->setLength(sat->orbitRadius()-EARTH_RADIUS);

What C++ material class and material parameters can I use to draw very faint transparent objects?
This seems easy in QML using shader fragments. How can one do this in C++?
        CustomMaterial {
            shadingMode: CustomMaterial.Shaded
            fragmentShader: "material_transparent.frag"
        }

Transparent.frag
void MAIN()
{
    vec2 size = vec2(textureSize(SCREEN_TEXTURE, 0));
    vec2 uv = FRAGCOORD.xy / size;

    vec3 view = normalize(VIEW_VECTOR);
    vec3 projection = view - view * normalize(NORMAL);
    vec3 refraction = projection * projection;
    uv += refraction.xy * 0.5;

    vec3 col = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, uv).rgb;
    col = col * 0.8 + vec3(0.2);

    BASE_COLOR = vec4(col, 1.0);
}

EDIT: karlphilip suggested I use a QEffect. I tried something based on the Qt documentation (I could not find any example of this). This is what I tried but the status of glShader is invariably "NotReady" at the end. I must be missing something. Any ideas?
    Qt3DRender::QEffect *effect = new Qt3DRender::QEffect();

    // Create technique, render pass and shader
    Qt3DRender::QTechnique *gl3Technique = new Qt3DRender::QTechnique();
    Qt3DRender::QRenderPass *gl3Pass = new Qt3DRender::QRenderPass();
    Qt3DRender::QShaderProgram *glShader = new Qt3DRender::QShaderProgram();

    // Set the shader on the render pass
    gl3Pass->setShaderProgram(glShader);

    // Add the pass to the technique
    gl3Technique->addRenderPass(gl3Pass);

    // Set the targeted GL version for the technique
    gl3Technique->graphicsApiFilter()->setApi(Qt3DRender::QGraphicsApiFilter::OpenGL);
    gl3Technique->graphicsApiFilter()->setMajorVersion(3);
    gl3Technique->graphicsApiFilter()->setMinorVersion(1);
    gl3Technique->graphicsApiFilter()->setProfile(Qt3DRender::QGraphicsApiFilter::CoreProfile);

    // Add the technique to the effect
    effect->addTechnique(gl3Technique);

    QByteArray prog = glShader->loadSource(QUrl("qrc:/material_transparent.frag"));
    glShader->setFragmentShaderCode(prog);


You can still create a custom material in C++ that implements a QEffect that uses that shader.

I tried that. See edit added in main post for the code. I must be missing something because it does not work.

When rendering QPhongAlphaMaterial with low alpha values in a QML Scene3D object, the documentation recommends setting the SourceAlphaArg and DestinationAlphaArg properties to specific values. Adding the following statements in the C++ program fixed the rendering issue:
Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial *conemat = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial();
        
mat->setSourceAlphaArg(Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::Zero);
mat->setDestinationAlphaArg(Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::One);

Now I'll need to figure out how to do this on a QDiffuseSpecularMaterial which doesn't have those properties.


You could just use QPhongAlphaMaterial for the cylinder and call setAlpha() to set the desired transparency level. Here is a little screenshot that compares the rendering result of two alpha values:

And there is the Qt 5 source code of main.cpp that renders the 3D scene above:
#include <QApplication>

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include <QtGui/QScreen>

#include <Qt3DCore/qentity.h>
#include <Qt3DCore/qtransform.h>
#include <Qt3DCore/qaspectengine.h>

#include <Qt3DRender/qcamera.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qcameralens.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qmesh.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qtechnique.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qmaterial.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qeffect.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qtexture.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qrenderpass.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qsceneloader.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qpointlight.h>
#include <Qt3DRender/qrenderaspect.h>

#include <Qt3DExtras/qtorusmesh.h>
#include <Qt3DExtras/qforwardrenderer.h>
#include <Qt3DExtras/qt3dwindow.h>
#include <Qt3DExtras/qfirstpersoncameracontroller.h>

#include <Qt3DExtras/QConeMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongAlphaMaterial>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //
    // Create window with 3D context using a 'blue' background color
    //

    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow *view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
    view->defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(QRgb(0x0000FF)));

    //
    // Instantiate main 3D entity
    //

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    view->setRootEntity(rootEntity);

    //
    // Setup camera
    //

    Qt3DRender::QCamera *cameraEntity = view->camera();
    cameraEntity->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    cameraEntity->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 20.0f));
    cameraEntity->setUpVector(QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
    cameraEntity->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    // Setup camera controls
    Qt3DExtras::QFirstPersonCameraController *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QFirstPersonCameraController(rootEntity);
    camController->setCamera(cameraEntity);

    //
    // Setup light source
    //

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DRender::QPointLight *light = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);
    light->setColor("white");
    light->setIntensity(1);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lightEntity);
    lightTransform->setTranslation(cameraEntity->position());

    lightEntity->addComponent(light);
    lightEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);

    //
    // Add cylinder to the 3D scene
    //

    // Setup cone shape
    Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh *cone = new Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh();
    cone->setTopRadius(0.5);
    cone->setBottomRadius(1);
    cone->setLength(3);
    cone->setRings(50);
    cone->setSlices(20);

    // Setup ConeMesh transform
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *coneTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
    coneTransform->setScale(3.f);
    coneTransform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 45.0f));
    coneTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));

    // Setup ConeMesh material
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial *coneMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial();
    coneMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0x00FF00)));
    coneMaterial->setAlpha(1.0f);

    // Add new cone entity to the 3D scene
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *coneEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    coneEntity->addComponent(cone);
    coneEntity->addComponent(coneMaterial);
    coneEntity->addComponent(coneTransform);

    // Display 3D window
    view->show();
    view->resize(800, 600);

    return a.exec();
}

Don't forget to add the following Qt3D modules to the QT variable on the .pro file:
3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dextras


Thanks for this, it validates my original approach. I was using QDiffuseSpecularMaterial because QPhongAlpha is deprecated, but trying with QPhongAlpha exactly like in your code still renders almost opaque white objects despite the color being set to green. Something else in the setup is interfering with the proper rendering. I'll keep looking.

To be honest, the entire Qt3D module will be deprecated after Qt 6.8. The QPhongAlphaMaterial class has been part of Qt3D for many years and its one of the most simple materials. I've even written my own version of it for fun. I can't see a good reason to stop using this class for now.

Just when I started getting good results with it. Sigh...

My program normally renders into a QML Scene3D object and low alpha materials are not rendered correctly. When rendering the exact same code directly in a Qt3DWindow from C++ instead of a Scene3D object in QML, the alpha parameter works just as expected and gives me the exact result I want. I'm onto something...
